# Restructure list by swap dimension and convert to numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, reshape

I have a list of list of list in the following format:

```
[ [[a1_1, a1_2, a1_3, a1_4], [b1_1, b1_2, b1_3, b1_4]],
  [[a2_1, a2_2, a2_3, a2_4], [b2_1, b2_2, b2_3, b2_4]],
         :
         :
  [[a10_1, a10_2, a10_3, a10_4], [b10_1, b10_2, b10_3, b10_4]] ]
```

Except iterate over each element and add it to the new structure, is there an elegant way to accomplish the following:

Restructure the list to:

```
  [ [[ a1_1,  b1_1], [a1_2, b1_2], [a1_3, b1_3], [a1_4, b1_4]], 
    [[ a2_1,  b2_1], [a2_2, b2_2], [a2_3, b2_3], [a2_4, b2_4]],
               :
               :
    [[ a10_1,  b10_1], [a10_2, b10_2], [a10_3, b10_3], [a10_4, b10_4]] ]
```

Then convert the above list of list of list to numpy structure in the shape of 10 x 4 x 2. Thanks!

Comment: Always use the generic Python tag, only use version-specific tags if your question is version specific (which it doesn't seem to be).

Comment: You could make it into an array, as is, and then reshape or swap axes.  These things are often easier with arrays than lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**use `tranpose`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) here:

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array(data)
```

and then:

```
ar.transpose((0,2,1))
```

or equivalent:

```
ar.transpose(0,2,1)
```

If I write strings into the variables, and then use your sample data, I get:

```
>>> ar
array([[['a_1_1', 'a_1_2', 'a_1_3', 'a_1_4'],
        ['b_1_1', 'b_1_2', 'b_1_3', 'b_1_4']],

       [['a_2_1', 'a_2_2', 'a_2_3', 'a_2_4'],
        ['b_2_1', 'b_2_2', 'b_2_3', 'b_2_4']],

       [['a_10_1', 'a_10_2', 'a_10_3', 'a_10_4'],
        ['b_10_1', 'b_10_2', 'b_10_3', 'b_10_4']]],
      dtype='<U6')
>>> ar.transpose((0,2,1))
array([[['a_1_1', 'b_1_1'],
        ['a_1_2', 'b_1_2'],
        ['a_1_3', 'b_1_3'],
        ['a_1_4', 'b_1_4']],

       [['a_2_1', 'b_2_1'],
        ['a_2_2', 'b_2_2'],
        ['a_2_3', 'b_2_3'],
        ['a_2_4', 'b_2_4']],

       [['a_10_1', 'b_10_1'],
        ['a_10_2', 'b_10_2'],
        ['a_10_3', 'b_10_3'],
        ['a_10_4', 'b_10_4']]],
      dtype='<U6')
```

`transpose` takes as input an array and a list of indices. It rearanges the indices such that (in case we give it `(0,2,1)`), the old first (`0`) dimension; is the new first dimension, the old third (`2`) dimension, is the new second dimension, and the old second (`1`) dimension is the new third dimension.

Comment: Never knew `.transpose` took an `*axes` parameter!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: me neither :), it was by accident :)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a list, you should be able to accomplish this relatively painlessly, just use the `zip` transpose idiom on the sublists:

```
arr = np.array([list(zip(*sub)) for sub in my_list])
```

So, using only 3-rows...

```
In [1]: data = [ [['a1_1', 'a1_2', 'a1_3', 'a1_4'], ['b1_1', 'b1_2', 'b1_3', 'b1_4']],
   ...:          [['a2_1', 'a2_2', 'a2_3', 'a2_4'], ['b2_1', 'b2_2', 'b2_3', 'b2_4']],
   ...:          [['a10_1', 'a10_2', 'a10_3', 'a10_4'], ['b10_1', 'b10_2', 'b10_3', 'b10_4']] ]

In [2]: [list(zip(*sub)) for sub in data]
Out[2]:
[[('a1_1', 'b1_1'), ('a1_2', 'b1_2'), ('a1_3', 'b1_3'), ('a1_4', 'b1_4')],
 [('a2_1', 'b2_1'), ('a2_2', 'b2_2'), ('a2_3', 'b2_3'), ('a2_4', 'b2_4')],
 [('a10_1', 'b10_1'), ('a10_2', 'b10_2'), ('a10_3', 'b10_3'), ('a10_4', 'b10_4')]]

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: np.array([list(zip(*sub)) for sub in data])
Out[4]:
array([[['a1_1', 'b1_1'],
        ['a1_2', 'b1_2'],
        ['a1_3', 'b1_3'],
        ['a1_4', 'b1_4']],

       [['a2_1', 'b2_1'],
        ['a2_2', 'b2_2'],
        ['a2_3', 'b2_3'],
        ['a2_4', 'b2_4']],

       [['a10_1', 'b10_1'],
        ['a10_2', 'b10_2'],
        ['a10_3', 'b10_3'],
        ['a10_4', 'b10_4']]],
      dtype='<U5')

In [5]: np.array([list(zip(*sub)) for sub in data]).shape
Out[5]: (3, 4, 2)
```

Comment: `zip(*)` is the list version `transpose`.

Comment: @hpaulj yep, well, it works on arbitrary iterables, but I wasn't aware that `np.ndarray.transpose` took an `*axes` parameter!

Comment: There are also swap and roll versions, but I think of `transpose` as the basic one.